# MobileFirst 7.1 Progurd getting Error return code 1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, proguard, cordova-plugin-proguard

I'm using mobilefirst 7.1 environment in eclipse. I just create sample hybrid application and add android environment. then i take unsigned apk at the time i'm getting below error. kindly help me for this.

Thank you :)

Progurd-project.txt

```
    # To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-injars libs/jmdns.jar 

# Using Google's License Verification Library 
-keep class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Specifies to write out some more information during processing. 
# If the program terminates with an exception, this option will print out the entire stack trace, instead of just the exception message.
-verbose

####################################################################################################
##############################  IBM MobileFirst Platform configuration  ############################
####################################################################################################
# Annotations are represented by attributes that have no direct effect on the execution of the code. 
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keep class **.R
-keep class **.R$* {
    <fields>;
}

# These options let obfuscated applications or libraries produce stack traces that can still be deciphered later on 
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile    
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# Enable proguard with Cordova
-keep class org.apache.cordova.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin

-keep class com.worklight.androidgap.push.** { *; }
-keep class com.worklight.wlclient.push.** { *; }
-keep class com.worklight.common.security.AppAuthenticityToken { *; }

# Enable proguard with Google libs
-keep class com.google.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**

# apache.http
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-optimizations !class/merging/vertical*,!class/merging/horizontal*,!code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!code/allocation/variable

-keep class net.sqlcipher.** { *; }
-dontwarn net.sqlcipher.**

-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Remove debug logs in release build
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
}

# These classes contain references to external jars which are not included in the default MobileFirst project.
-dontwarn com.worklight.common.internal.WLTrusteerInternal*
-dontwarn com.worklight.jsonstore.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.*
-dontwarn com.worklight.androidgap.push.GCMIntentService
-dontwarn com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLInitializationPlugin
-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.push.GCMIntentService
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.security.SecurityManager

-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.push.WLBroadcastReceiver
-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.push.common.*
-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush
-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.api.SecurityUtils

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory
-dontwarn android.net.http.*
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
################################################################################
```

Console Error

```
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Note: there were 3284 duplicate class definitions.
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.JFrame
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser$ServiceTableModel: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced method 'java.awt.Container getContentPane()' in class com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class java.awt.GridLayout
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class java.awt.GridLayout
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JList
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JList
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JList
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JList
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JList
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JList
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JPanel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JPanel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class java.awt.BorderLayout
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class java.awt.BorderLayout
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JPanel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JLabel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JLabel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JPanel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JScrollPane
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JScrollPane
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced method 'void setDefaultCloseOperation(int)' in class com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced method 'void setLocation(int,int)' in class com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced method 'void setSize(int,int)' in class com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced method 'void setVisible(boolean)' in class com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.SwingUtilities
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JList
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JPanel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.SwingUtilities
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JList
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JList
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser: can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser$2: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser$2: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser$ServiceTableModel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser$ServiceTableModel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser$ServiceTableModel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser$ServiceTableModel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: com.strangeberry.jmdns.tools.Browser$ServiceTableModel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.easymock.EasyMock
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.easymock.EasyMock
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.easymock.Capture
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.easymock.Capture
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.easymock.EasyMock
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.easymock.EasyMock
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.easymock.Capture
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.easymock.Capture
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.easymock.EasyMock
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.easymock.EasyMock
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Before
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.JmDNSTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.ServiceInfoTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Before
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.ServiceInfoTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.ServiceInfoTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.ServiceInfoTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.ServiceInfoTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.ServiceInfoTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.ServiceInfoTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.ServiceInfoTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.ServiceInfoTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.ServiceInfoTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.TextUpdateTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Before
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.TextUpdateTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.TextUpdateTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: javax.jmdns.test.TextUpdateTest: can't find referenced class org.junit.Test
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: there were 105 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] Warning: there were 5 unresolved references to program class members.
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2016-12-06 12:46:55 - progurdProgurdAndroid]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried the same. It works perfectly fine. From the error logs it is clear that there are references to awt and swing API's which are not being found. MobileFirst does not bundle these dependencies in its project. Please check the libraries or dependencies added to your project.

Comment: Thank you **S.A.Norton Stanley**